# Set dictionary value with a function?

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I am trying to do the following on my main.js file, but it doesn't seem to work.
$t is a vue-i18n function.
Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

```js
Vue.prototype.$state = [
  {value: "New York", label: this.$t('states.newyork')}
]
```

Comment: Where are you running that code?

Comment: It's inside Vue's main.js

Comment: Then what do you expect `this` to be in your code above?

Comment: Oh, you are right, it should a reference issue. Maybe I have to import i18n and call its function.